# Пагинация в API при нескольких таблицах

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, пагинация

Возникла небольшая проблема, пока нет идей как это решить. (UNION, JOIN, Декартово произведение - плохие идеи) :)
**Проблема**: При реализации rest api на определенной точке идет запрос на поиск в базе по параметру, причем поиск ведется по нескольким таблицам. Будем считать, что общее число таблиц N, а общее число записей в некоторых таблицах может быть достаточно велико, чтобы разом запрашивать все записи

- Это было бы просто, не будь таблиц N-ое количество, каждая из которых содержит разное количество разных столбцов.
- Таким образом, у имеется база в которой необходимо произвести поиск по параметру и найти совпадения в каждой из таблиц. Но вывод нужно разбить по лимиту 10 записей, если лимит добавлять в каждый из запросов, то в общем будет не 10, а 10 * [Количество страниц].

Нужно как-то объединить все таблицы для удобства и брать по limit = 10, но операция объединения происходит тоже долго, если записей много.

Comment: Использовать materialized view? В котором будут заранее объединённые данные.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Пока не представляю как вообще таблицы могут быть объединены, если там разные столбцы и разное их количество. 
materialized view первый раз слышу, надо изучить как вообще это работает)

Comment: Приведите какой-то пример, чтоб было понятно, что (по смыслу) должен возвращать запрос. В такой формулировке вообще не ясно что возвращается (объекты одного типа или нет, объекты сами по себе или иерархия и т.д.), к чему лимит применяется и т.д.

Comment: Из базы возвращается объект с полями для каждой таблицы. Использую pymysql, затем этот объект конвертирую в json и возвращаю это уже на flask. Заголовок вопроса я так понял общая проблема. Пагинация нужна, чтобы разом сильно базу не нагружать, но пагинация без проблем работает, если одна таблицы, но если их несколько, то возникает проблема с объединением из-за разного количества столбцов и само объединение может занять много времени